# How to use the expanduser and exists modules together

Tags: python, module

Here's the code first

```
    user = os.path.expanduser('~\AppData\Local\Temp')
    os.path.exists(user,'\whatever.txt')
```

Now the problem is, when I run it it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "pyshell#7", line 1, in module
>   os.path.exists(user,'\whatever.txt')
>
> TypeError: exists() takes exactly 1
>   argument (2 given)

How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join two path fragments together:

```
os.path.exists(os.path.join(user,'whatever.txt'))
```

Note that `r'\whatever.txt'` is an absolute path, so 
`os.path.join(user,r'\whatever.txt')` would return `r'\whatever.txt'`, ignoring the value of `user`.

If you want to look for `whatever.txt` inside the `user` directory, then you need to use a relative path by removing the backslash.

PS: Python assigns special meaning to certain characters preceded by backslashes. `'\t'` is a tab character for example. You generally don't intend for backslashes to be interpreted in this way in a path, so -- even though all the backslashes in your post are interpreted literally -- it is generally a good idea to get in the habit of using raw strings (e.g. `r'~\AppData\Local\Temp'` to specify paths so you don't get unexpected surprises later. Or, you could use forward slashes instead: `'~/AppData/Local/Temp'`.